# Java - adding JButton array to JFrame

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

I am trying to add a 2D JButton array to a JFrame, I don't get any errors, just the JButtons don't show up.

Creating the JButtons:

```
public class TTTGrid {
private static JFrame frame;
private static int[][] coords;
private static int width, height;
public TTTGrid(JFrame frame,int[][] coords, int width, int height){
    this.frame = frame;
    this.coords = coords;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
static JButton map[][] = new JButton[3][3];

public void Draw(){
    for(int i = 0; i<coords.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<coords[i].length; j++){
            map[i][j] = new JButton();
            map[i][j].setBounds(i*100, j*100, width, height);
            frame.add(map[i][j]);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Where the draw method is called:

```
public class TTTthread extends TTT implements Runnable {
int[][] map = new int[3][3];
TTTGrid grid = new TTTGrid(frame, map, 100, 100);

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            grid.Draw();

            Thread.sleep(20);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is running like I think it's running, you appear to be trying to add 9 JButtons to your GUI 50 times a second! That's a heck of a lot of buttons -- are you sure that this is what you want to be doing? Your code also runs far afoul of Swing threading rules by making Swing calls (a **lot** of Swing calls!) off of the Swing event thread.

Your main solution is likely to

- Add your 9 JButtons to a JPanel that uses a `GridLayout(3, 3)`
- Do this only **once** not 50 times a second
- Then add that JPanel to your GUI, BorderLayout.CENTER and to be sure not to use `null` layouts.
- Not try to set the bounds, size or locations of these JButtons, but rather to let the layout managers to the work
- Get rid of that while loop and instead change your code to be more event-driven using Swing's event driven model.
- Strive to use mostly non-static variables and methods so that your classes become true OOPS-compliant classes, allowing them to take advantage of the benefits of OOPS programming, including reducing program complexity and interconnectedness (reduce coupling).

---

For example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyTttFoo extends JPanel {
   // it's OK for constants to be static
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final int ROWS = 3;

   // use a larger Font to make buttons larger
   private static final Font BTN_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 60);
   private static final String BLANK = "   ";
   private static final String X = "X";
   private static final String O = "O";

   // but not most variables
   private JButton[][] buttonGrid = new JButton[ROWS][ROWS];

   public MyTttFoo() {
      setBackground(Color.black);

      // use layout managers to help you create your GUI
      setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, ROWS, 1, 1));
      ActionListener btnListener = new ButtonListener();
      // create your buttons and add them only **once**
      for (int row = 0; row < buttonGrid.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < buttonGrid[row].length; col++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(BLANK);
            button.setFont(BTN_FONT);
            button.addActionListener(btnListener);
            add(button);  // add button to a gridlayout using component
            buttonGrid[row][col] = button; // and assign into the array
         }
      }
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      private boolean xTurn = true;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         AbstractButton btn = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
         String txt = btn.getText();
         if (txt.equals(BLANK)) {
            if (xTurn) {
               btn.setText(X);
            } else {
               btn.setText(O);               
            }
            xTurn = !xTurn;
         } 
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MyTttFoo mainPanel = new MyTttFoo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyTttFoo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```